please solve my error " TypeError: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name' "in odoo16 pycharm project
 File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\software\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\software\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import ir_mail_server
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\software\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_mail_server.py", line 19, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto as SSLCrypto
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\odoo16.0\odoo-16.0\Lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import SSL, crypto
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\odoo16.0\odoo-16.0\Lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 34, in <module>
    from OpenSSL.crypto import (
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\odoo16.0\odoo-16.0\Lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 942, in <module>
    utils.deprecated(
TypeError: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

2024-06-12 10:42:53,196 1428 CRITICAL ? odoo.modules.module: Couldn't load module web 
2024-06-12 10:42:53,196 1428 CRITICAL ? odoo.modules.module: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name' 
2024-06-12 10:42:53,196 1428 ERROR ? odoo.service.server: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\software\odoo-16.0\odoo\service\server.py", line 1259, in load_server_wide_modules
    odoo.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\software\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\module.py", line 471, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "c:\users\yasir\desktop\software\odoo-16.0\addons\web\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import controllers
  File "c:\users\yasir\desktop\software\odoo-16.0\addons\web\controllers\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import database
  File "c:\users\yasir\desktop\software\odoo-16.0\addons\web\controllers\database.py", line 19, in <module>
    from odoo.addons.base.models.ir_qweb import render as qweb_render
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\software\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\software\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import ir_mail_server
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\software\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_mail_server.py", line 19, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto as SSLCrypto
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\odoo16.0\odoo-16.0\Lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import SSL, crypto
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\odoo16.0\odoo-16.0\Lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 34, in <module>
    from OpenSSL.crypto import (
  File "C:\Users\Yasir\Desktop\odoo16.0\odoo-16.0\Lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 942, in <module>
    utils.deprecated(
TypeError: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

I have this error while I was making a custom module for odoo16 in a pycharm project .. I have python 3.12 as an interpreter and pycharm 2024. when I make init and manifest file in custom directory and run, it shows the error..manifest file also asked to install cryptography 3.4.8 as required and I installed...I have searched online and reinstalled cryptography, upgraded openssl but could not find the solution, please help...

Does the problem occur if you're running Python outside of Pycharm? There was a similar TypeError question for Boto3 but it doesn't have an answer. The last suggestion there was to reconfigure the AWS client. The other thing that you could check is your project config's addons_path and whether it points to directories with a module called web.
